# Why does source code of MAVEN cloneing from github but find some of class file is missing

Tags: maven

I have clone the source code of maven from github ;when I view the code , discover that part of the class file was missing.

AH, I want to learning source coed of maven , so I cloneed the code from the github ,but I didn't check the quick start prompt below ,(Then I found that there are no corresponding classes in many specified reference paths ，some of the java file did not compile) ,this disturted me a few days , atfer I buiid the enviromment by code 'mvn -DdistributionTargetDir="$HOME/app/maven/apache-maven-4.0.x-SNAPSHOT" clean package' ,  problem was gone away

Comment: Do not use images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328 apart from that have you build it locally because some of the files a generated...which causes this..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

when I read the instructions from the https://github.com/apache/maven where the end of the article，there have a title which is "Quick start" .Yes, I have not specifying a location into which the completed Maven distro before run maven source code .I'm so stupide ,Aha!